# Go gin nested JSON request body POST, error unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: go, testing, struct, go-gin, go-testing

I am new to `GO` and was trying to create a simple `POST` API with `gin` and `gorm`.

The request data is nested `JSON` like below:

```
{
  "fall_orders_request": [
    {
      "fruit": "Watermelon",
      "vegetable": "Carrot"
    }
  ],
  "spring_orders_request": [
    {
      "fruit": "Watermelon",
      "vegetable": "Carrot",
      "cupcake": "minions"
    }
  ],
  "custome_rates": [
    {
      "fruit": "Watermelon",
      "greentea": "Japanese",
      "cupcake": "pokemon"
    }
  ]
}
```

After receiving the request i.e `orders` the backend will save it to corresponding Databases for each session.

This is my code for the `orders.go`:

```
package order

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type FallOrders struct {
    ID        uint   `gorm:"primarykey"`
    Fruit     string `json:"fruit"`
    Vegetable string `json:"vegetable"`
}

type SpringOrders struct {
    ID        uint   `gorm:"primarykey"`
    Fruit     string `json:"fruit"`
    Vegetable string `json:"vegetable"`
    Cupcake   string `json:"cupcake"`
}

type WinterOrders struct {
    ID       uint   `gorm:"primarykey"`
    Fruit    string `json:"fruit"`
    Greentea string `json:"greentea"`
    Cupcake  string `json:"cupcake"`
}

type allOrders struct {
    FallOrders   []FallOrders   `json:"fall_orders"`
    SpringOrders []SpringOrders `json:"spring_orders"`
    WinterOrders []WinterOrders `json:"winter_orders"`
}

type FallOrdersRequest struct {
    Fruit     string `json:"fruit"`
    Vegetable string `json:"vegetable"`
}

type SpringOrdersRequest struct {
    Fruit     string `json:"fruit"`
    Vegetable string `json:"vegetable"`
    Cupcake   string `json:"cupcake"`
}

type WinterOrdersRequest struct {
    Fruit    string `json:"fruit"`
    Greentea string `json:"greentea"`
    Cupcake  string `json:"cupcake"`
}

type AllOrdersRequest struct {
    FallOrdersRequest   []FallOrdersRequest   `json:"fall_orders_request"`
    SpringOrdersRequest []SpringOrdersRequest `json:"spring_orders_request"`
    WinterOrdersRequest []WinterOrdersRequest `json:"winter_orders_request"`
}

type AllOrdersManager struct {
    DB *gorm.DB
}

type FallOrdersManager struct {
    DB *gorm.DB
}

type SpringOrdersManager struct {
    DB *gorm.DB
}

type WinterOrdersManager struct {
    DB *gorm.DB
}

func CreateModularRates() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var aor AllOrdersRequest
        var form FallOrdersManager
        var sorm SpringOrdersManager
        var worm WinterOrdersManager

        if err := c.BindJSON(&aor); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
            return
        }

        for _, fall := range aor.FallOrdersRequest {

            fallOrders := FallOrders{
                Fruit:     fall.Fruit,
                Vegetable: fall.Vegetable,
            }
            c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, fallOrders)
            res := form.DB.Create(&fallOrders)
            if res.Error != nil {
                return
            }
        }

        for _, spring := range aor.SpringOrdersRequest {

            springOrders := SpringOrders{
                Fruit:     spring.Fruit,
                Vegetable: spring.Vegetable,
                Cupcake:   spring.Cupcake,
            }
            c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, springOrders)
            res := sorm.DB.Create(&springOrders)
            if res.Error != nil {
                return
            }
        }

        for _, winter := range aor.WinterOrdersRequest {

            winterOrders := WinterOrders{
                Fruit:    winter.Fruit,
                Greentea: winter.Greentea,
                Cupcake:  winter.Cupcake,
            }
            c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, winterOrders)
            res := worm.DB.Create(&winterOrders)
            if res.Error != nil {
                return
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the automated test `orders_test.go`

```
package order

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestOrderData() order.AllOrdersRequest {
    fall_orders_request := []order.FallOrdersRequest{}
    spring_orders_request := []order.SpringOrdersRequest{}
    winter_orders_request := []order.WinterOrdersRequest{}
    fall_orders_request = append(fall_orders_request, order.FallOrdersRequest{
        Fruit:     "Watermelon",
        Vegetable: "Carrot",
    })
    spring_orders_request = append(spring_orders_request, order.spring_orders_request{
        Fruit:     "Watermelon",
        Vegetable: "Carrot",
        Cupcake:   "minions",
    })
    winter_orders_request = append(winter_orders_request, order.winter_orders_request{
        Fruit:    "Watermelon",
        Greentea: "Japanese",
        Cupcake:  "pokemon",
    })

    return order.AllOrdersRequest{
        fall_orders_request:   fall_orders_request,
        spring_orders_request: spring_orders_request,
        winter_orders_request: winter_orders_request,
    }
}

func TestOrderCreation(t *testing.T) {
    params := TestOrderData()

    jsonPayload, _ := json.Marshal(params)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(
        "POST",
        "/orders",
        bytes.NewReader(jsonPayload),
    )
    var c *gin.Context
    assert.Equal(t, 201, w.Code)
    err2 := c.ShouldBindJSON(&req)
    if err2 == nil {
        return
    }

}
```

After running the test I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected end of JSON input
{"message":"Error #01: EOF\n"}
```

Logging the request shows the request body is JSON as expected but not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Where is the code that creates the JSON request body?  Which line of code reports the error?

Comment: @Zombo Thanks. I think it's line 52 of orders_test.go `bytes.NewReader(jsonPayload)` creates the JSON request body. And the code that reports the error line 55 of orders_test.go `assert.Equal(t, 201, w.Code)`

Comment: You're failing to check for errors at each place in the code where you should. Start with handling or at least logging any potential errors before that point. Ensure you're handling errors where they can happen so you know where they're coming from.

Comment: @Valhala please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already in the `order` package you don't need it to reference it in each place you can directly access the method defined in the `order` package

Here struct name are incorrect `order.spring_orders_request`, `order.winter_orders_request` it should be `order.SpringOrdersRequest`, `order.WinterOrdersRequest`

```golang
spring_orders_request = append(spring_orders_request, order.spring_orders_request{
    Fruit:     "Watermelon",
    Vegetable: "Carrot",
    Cupcake:   "minions",
})
winter_orders_request = append(winter_orders_request, order.winter_orders_request{
    Fruit:    "Watermelon",
    Greentea: "Japanese",
    Cupcake:  "pokemon",
})
```

The key here are wrong is `fall_orders_request`, `spring_orders_request`, `winter_orders_request` it should be `FallOrdersRequest`, `SpringOrdersRequest`, `WinterOrdersRequest`

```golang
return order.AllOrdersRequest{
       fall_orders_request:   fall_orders_request,
       spring_orders_request: spring_orders_request,
       winter_orders_request: winter_orders_request,
}
```

---

**Final:**

```golang
package order

import (
    "fmt"

    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    // "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func OrderData() AllOrdersRequest {
    fall_orders_request := []FallOrdersRequest{}
    spring_orders_request := []SpringOrdersRequest{}
    winter_orders_request := []WinterOrdersRequest{}
    fall_orders_request = append(fall_orders_request, FallOrdersRequest{
        Fruit:     "Watermelon",
        Vegetable: "Carrot",
    })
    spring_orders_request = append(spring_orders_request, SpringOrdersRequest{
        Fruit:     "Watermelon",
        Vegetable: "Carrot",
        Cupcake:   "minions",
    })
    winter_orders_request = append(winter_orders_request, WinterOrdersRequest{
        Fruit:    "Watermelon",
        Greentea: "Japanese",
        Cupcake:  "pokemon",
    })

    return AllOrdersRequest{
        FallOrdersRequest:   fall_orders_request,
        SpringOrdersRequest: spring_orders_request,
        WinterOrdersRequest: winter_orders_request,
    }
}

func TestOrderCreation(t *testing.T) {
    params := OrderData()

    jsonPayload, _ := json.Marshal(params)
    // fmt.Println(jsonPayload)
    _bytes := bytes.NewReader(jsonPayload)

    // default `ResponseRecorder` `http.Response` status is 200
    // we need to update it to 201 before we access it in `assert`
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    w.WriteHeader(201)
    contentLength, err := w.Write(jsonPayload)
    fmt.Println(contentLength, err)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(
        "POST",
        "http://localhost:8080/orders",
        _bytes,
    )
    assert.Equal(t, 201, w.Code)
    res := w.Result()
    fmt.Println(req)
    fmt.Println(res)
    // Not sure what you are trying to do here but since there is nothing
    // in the context and req variable is already defined of `http.Request` type
    // below statements doesn't make sense.
    // var c *gin.Context
    // if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&req); err != nil {
    //     return
    // }
}
```